# Why Google Cache Showing 404 on my React Base Webpages?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, cache, google-cache, react-js

My web page is client-side rendered with React.
On hitting the cache, it is showing 404 instead of a rendered page.

**Example Screenshot**
[image]

When I inspect the Page URL on Search Console, Its parsing and rendering my page properly on Google Index as well as on Live Test.

**Example Screenshots**
[image]
[image]

Why cache page is showing 404? Is the Client-side react is responsible? If not then what is the issue? Or will it be resolved automatically in a few days?

**Note**
It's my new site which recently goes live in last week.

Comment: In general you have to give Google several weeks after making any changes.   I'm not sure if this is react client side related or not, but there is certainly a possibility that you just haven't given Google enough time.

Comment: May this website helps  you:https://i-verve.com/blog/website-showing-404-error-in-google-cache-how-we-fixed-it/

Comment: What cache are you referring to? Cloudflare? Browser cache? What is the website so I can take a look?

Comment: @SimpliFixed I assume the poster is referring to the cache link on the right side of search results.